# Why is PEP-801 reserved?

Tags: python, pep

I was scrolling through the [PEP index page](https://peps.python.org/) and noticed that a PEP number was reserved by ‘Warsaw’:

> |  | PEP | PEP Title | PEP Author(s) |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | I | 801 | Reserved | Warsaw |

I looked it up out of curiosity and the only thing I found referencing this was the [PEP index page](https://peps.python.org/) and [this commit](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-checkins/2013-October/124775.html) from 2013 which didn't answer my question

In the commit, they explain that it could be for humour reason (like 666 for example) but I don't see why 801. What is that number linked to?

Comment: Since there are no other reserved PEP numbers, it seems that it's placeholder for future reserved numbers. Meta-reserved PEP, in other words.

Comment: @el.pescado I've just went `back in time` to try and see if I could find a link between the `801` and the date where it was added, and it really seems like a random number. PEPs `800` and `799` don't exist so it can''t be the number that was next when created

Comment: Maybe it's some joke from the Monty Python show. I can't say for sure 'cause I've never watched it. [Here is why it's a possibility](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/general.html#why-is-it-called-python)

Comment: You might have more luck asking on the [python-list mailing list](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-list).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better asked of the Python developer(s) (mailing list).

Comment: @Michael, wouldn't that be true of *all* questions related to developing the Python code base, such as the 440-odd questions tagged `[python-internals]`? How is this question any different from (for example) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067395/gnu-stl-string-is-copy-on-write-involved-here which probably should be on one of the the GNU mailing lists? :-) As far as I can tell, this question ticks the boxes for a "kosher" SO one.

Comment: @paxdiablo; no, I don't think so - this is specifically about the rationale of a choice made by the development team, which is undocumented.

Comment: It seems notable that there are no other PEPs in the 800-900 range, while there are PEPs in the 100-800 range, again points towards the placeholder explanation

Comment: @Gabriel As a Monty Python fan, I can't think of why 801 would have any meaning in that context

Comment: How was this question asked in April 2018 when PEP 801 was [created in June 2018](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0801/)?

Comment: Because when I asked this question, This pep was reserved in the first pep and never created as a pep as a web page. Guess they just made it

Comment: In other words, I'm a time traveler ‍♂️

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Warning, this is supposition, though investigated as at *least* being plausible.

If you look at the history for the `python\peps\pep0` file (the listing of all PEPs), you'll find the [change](https://github.com/python/peps/commit/840b60217295c00f09eba39cf3fe25883ecae4a1#diff-b1bd6396f6f47b94583214a986c62259) was done in October 2013 by one Barry Warsaw, so probably nothing to do with any Polish Python user group as some surmise :-)

I can really only suggest why *I* would have done such a thing and, based on that, the most likely reason for it would be to either test that the changes would work with some random value, or that a placeholder of some sort was needed. Short of asking the author himself (which I have now done, so stay tuned ...), that's probably the most likely reason for now.

---

After receiving a reply from the author, the reason is as simple as it was related to some song/band back in those days, possibly [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/801_%28band%29). The email reply follows:

> You’ve both reached out to me about the same topic and SO thread, so I
> hope you don’t mind me responding to you both.  First, thanks for your
> love of Python!  It’s a fantastic language, and even better community,
> and it’s been a great place to have spent the better part of my
> professional career.
>
> What better than a minor mystery in a corner of a language?  Python,
> named after the Monty Python troupe, has a rich history of humor and
> easter eggs, so 801 could be nothing more than that.  An enigma,
> wrapped in a riddle, stuffed into a conundrum.  A turducken PEP.
>
> Maybe you’re right, and it’s the secret key that unlocks the Polish
> Python Ploy, a conspiracy of Warsawans to take over the language from
> the Dastardly Dutch Dozen.  Or it could be a number, that when fed to
> a certain Python stdlib API, takes over your speakers and unstoppably
> plays the entire series of Flying Circus until you Silly Walk
> accurately in front of your webcam.
>
> I like to think it’s just a fun number that named a song and a band
> some people were into back in the day, coupled with the abuse of power
> from a mad PEP editor everyone else is too afraid to question.  Only
> the Python Secret Underground (PSU) -which emphatically does not
> exist- knows for sure.
>
> Cheers,
> -Barry

Answer (score 3):

Some PEPs are not numbered sequentially, but are numbered based on their content.  Examples are:

- [PEP 628](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0628/) adding math.tau, so named because tau is approximately 6.28,
- [PEP 754](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/), implementing the IEEE 754 standard, named after the standard number

Now what if I want to start writing a PEP, I desire for it to have a special number, but I haven't written it yet?  Then we can ask the PEP manager!  On 21 June 2018, PEP numbers 801 was reserved in [this pull request](https://github.com/python/peps/pull/683).  Initially, PEP 581 was reserved as well, but this reservation was [withdrawn](https://github.com/python/peps/pull/683/commits/4d9ea1f3c670c407e22696ffa1227894c5d30284).

So, presumably people reserved PEP 801 and 581 because they are preparing a PEP for which this number has a special meaning, and they don't want that number to be assigned to any other PEP.

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't explain why they reserved that random pep number